# how to get the angularjs scope id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

referring to this question [angularjs: directive creates two child scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307585/angularjs-directive-creates-two-child-scopenot-isolation-scope-and-how-to-ge). How is it possible to get the scope id in question.

i.e. the **Scope (003)**, **Scope (004)** etc

Comment: Use angular.element("#element").scope().$id

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get any scopes id by console logging it:

Controller:

```
function($scope){ //injected
    console.log($scope.$id);
}
```

Directive link function:

```
function(scope, element, attributes){
    console.log(scope.$id);
}
```